# ABTableViewCell selected lag

Tags: uitableview

I've successfuly subclassed ABTableViewCell for fast scrolling.
I really recommend it to anyone who's making an app with big tableViews...

http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/

My problem with it is that when I tap a row, there is a small delay until it gets selected. I tried to put [cell setSelected:true] in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of the tableView, and it still lags. Has anyone experienced this as well with a ABTableViewCell subclass?

I didn't have this issue using regular UITableViewCells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cell can be highlighted (on touchDown) or selected (on touchUp).

Code that came with ABTableViewCell:

```
if(self.selected) {
    backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    greyColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    blackColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Had to replace it with:

```
if(self.highlighted || self.selected) {
    backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    greyColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    blackColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

And that killed the cell selection lag.

Comment: where is if(self.selected) statement located?

Comment: I haven't used ABTableViewCell in a long, long time. Just search ABTableViewCell.m for it.